# Why does xrandr output brightness setting not persist? Is this a bug?

Tags: brightness, xrandr

Run

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness .4
```

Download an attachment in gmail in chrome.
The brightness resets itself to 1.

All kinds of other random moments kick the xrandr output setting back to default, so I run this command several times a day, just to have non-blinding monitor backlighting.

For example, closing the lid and opening the lid will also default back to insane-bright.

Comment: In many laptops there are hotkeys to increase and decrease the brightness. Would that be more convenient? If you find such hotkeys, check if the settings will persist. In external monitors, there are often buttons and menus to set the brightness (and contrast). I think that `xrandr` is modifying settings temporarily (also for example the resolution). You have to save the settings somewhere (as a script), and for example run a script via autostart.

Comment: That would be more convenient, but in Ubuntu, the increase/decrease brightness is held to an extremely high brightness. I have to use xrandr (or maybe another solution) to get a screen that doesn't hurt to look at, even on Ubuntu's "minimum" brightness.

Comment: I found an solution of this problem here --> https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/issues/102

Comment: THANK YOU. I followed the steps. Now will wait and see if the problem recurs.